# oidc-client.js raises "No authority passed" error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, single-sign-on, openid-connect, oidc-client-js

I'm a new comer for SSO. Recently I'm focusing on a project which is using OIDC. I try to use oidc-client to solve the problem. Here is my settings.(I erase the detail url, but they are effective).

```
var mgr = new Oidc.UserManager({
    userStore: new Oidc.WebStorageStateStore({ store: window.localStorage }),
    metadata: {
      issuer: 'https://foo.com/',
      authorization_endpoint: 'https://foo.com/',
      userinfo_endpoint: 'https://foo.com/',
      end_session_endpoint: 'https://foo.com/',
      jwks_uri: 'https://foo.com/'
    },
    keys: [
      {
        'kty': 'RSA',
        'kid': 'some info',
        'use': 'some info',
        'n': 'some info',
        'e': 'some info'
      }
    ],
    client_id: 'aaaaa',
    redirect_uri: 'https://foo.com/',
    response_type: 'id_token token',
    scope: 'openid'
  })
  Oidc.Log.logger = console
  Oidc.Log.level = Oidc.Log.INFO
  mgr.signinRedirect()
    .then(function () { console.log('Hello') }).catch(function (err) {
      console.log(err)
    })
```

But it hasn't redirected to the authorization_endpoint. Instead, it raises an error like following

> oidc-client.min.js?dd17:1 SigninRequest.ctor: No authority passed
>   error @ oidc-client.min.js?dd17:1 SigninRequest @
>   oidc-client.min.js?dd17:3 (anonymous) @ oidc-client.min.js?dd17:3
>   Promise.then (async) createSigninRequest @ oidc-client.min.js?dd17:3
>   (anonymous) @ oidc-client.min.js?dd17:3 Promise.then (async)
>   _signinStart @ oidc-client.min.js?dd17:3 signinRedirect @ oidc-client.min.js?dd17:3 onSubmit @ HelloWorld.vue?140d:71 click @
>   HelloWorld.vue?1f3f:21 invoker @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2023
>   fn._withTask.fn._withTask @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1822

I run the code under a vue-cli environment. But I don't think it will cause the problem. If you have met the similar problem, please tell me how to solve it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See required settings in https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/wiki

> **Required Settings**
>
> - authority (string): The URL of the OIDC/OAuth2 provider.

From the error and your code it looks like you are not setting authority